# Are there git hub projects available for reference to bring existing user Db to identity server 4? If there is one, point me to that

Tags: identityserver4

I have users Db built in Sql server and Have lot of columns based on application requirements. How do i use this users table in Identity server 4? Are there any git hub reference project to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own user class by inheriting from `IdentityUser`. There you can add your own properties and override the existing ones (to map them to your column names).

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }

    // these two properties are your custom ones
    public int? StaffId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    // here you map an Identity property to a column you already have
    [Column("LockoutEndDateUtc")]
    public override DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
}
```